# How to join/spread dataset to possible coordinate location within zone in R

Tags: r, join, spread

I hope anyone could give me a hints on which approach should I use.
For example I have a data frame as follows:

```
Zone <- c(1, 1,1,1,2,2,2)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
df1 <- data.frame(Zone, ID)


Zone <- c(1, 1,1,2,2,2,2)
X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

df2 <- data.frame(Zone,X, Y)
```

However when I combined them using simple join as shown, it gives wrong output.

```
df3 <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = "Zone")
```

I would like to get this possible result:

```
Zone <- c(1, 1,1,1,2,2,2)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
X <- c(1,2,3,2,5,6,7)
Y <- c(1,2,3,2,5,6,7)


df3 <- data.frame(Zone,ID, X, Y)
```

Thank you for your help or any approach that may work. Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand the connection between your input and expected output. How does that 4th row in `df3` get `X` and `Y` value as 2, 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `cbind` function to column-bind the dataframes:

```
df2 %>% cbind(df1$ID)
```

Output:

```
  Zone X Y df1$ID
1    1 1 1      1
2    1 2 2      2
3    1 3 3      3
4    2 4 4      4
5    2 5 5      5
6    2 6 6      6
7    2 7 7      7
```

Comment: Thank you. But df$Y = 4 is for zone 2.

Comment: However df1$ID = 4 is for zone 1.  Sorry.

Comment: @AnugrahIlahi So does my previous code work?

Comment: I am sorry but the df$Y = 4 is for zone 2

Answer (score 0):

We may use `bind_cols` after `select`ing the column of interest

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    bind_cols(df1 %>%
          select(ID))
   Zone X Y ID
1    1 1 1  1
2    1 2 2  2
3    1 3 3  3
4    2 4 4  4
5    2 5 5  5
6    2 6 6  6
7    2 7 7  7
```